# Send request type (GEG/POST etc.) as parameter

Tags: python, python-requests

Please see this function:

```
class HttpClient:
    @staticmethod
    def send_request(session: requests.sessions.Session, request_type: HttpRequestType, url: str, data: json, headers: dict):
        if request_type == HttpRequestType.GET:
            return session.get(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
        elif request_type == HttpRequestType.POST:
            return session.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)


class HttpRequestType(Enum):
    GET = 'Get'
    POST = 'Create'
    PUT = 'Update'
    DELETE = 'Delete'
```

So instead of use this `if-else` condition is it possible to pass the `post` or `get` type to this function ?

**EDIT**

```
url = 'my_url'
data = f'username=my_user&password=my_password&submit=Login'
headers = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

response = send_request(s.post, *[url, data, headers])

def send_request(func_to_use, *args):
    return func_to_use(*args)
```

**Usage**

```
response = send_request(s.post, *[url, data, headers])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can actually pass the function to use as an argument.

Here's a simplified example:

```
def send_request(func_to_use, *args):
    func_to_use(*args)

send_request(session.get, *['my', 'get', 'args'])
send_request(session.post, *['my', 'post', 'args'])
```

Should be easy enough to adapt this example to your specific needs.

---

Another approach, using getattr:

```
def send_request(session, method, *args):
    getattr(session, method)(*args)

send_request(session, 'get', *['my', 'get', 'args'])
send_request(session, 'post', *['my', 'post', 'args'])
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the first approach ? where is the request ?  why this send_request function use this func_to_use ?

Comment: As I said, those are simplified examples. You will still have to pass url, data, headers and w/e you need into the ``send_request`` method and also into the session's get/post method. The examples just show, that you can pass either the actual method (example 1) or the method name (example 2) as *additional* parameters, so you don't have to use if...else. You could even modify example 2 to use ``request_type`` instead of the param ``method`` (you'd need to convert the enum value to lowercase, though).

Comment: Please see my update according your code, I cannot login to my server, the log just say  Failed login for user: empty user